# Unbiasedness and consistency of OLS

Tags: least-squares, unbiased-estimator, consistency

Does unbiasedness of OLS in a linear regression model automatically imply consistency?

Edit: I am asking specifically about the assumptions for unbiasedness and consistency of OLS. If the assumptions for unbiasedness are fulfilled, does it mean that the assumptions for consistency are fulfilled as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily; Consistency is related to Large Sample size i.e. as we increase the number of samples, the estimate should converge to the true parameter - essentially, as $n \to \infty$, the $\text{var}(\hat\beta) \to 0$, in addition to $\Bbb E(\hat \beta) = \beta$.

Update:

Please refer to the proofs of unbiasedness and consistency for OLS [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_ordinary_least_squares#Consistency_and_asymptotic_normality_of_.CE.B2.CC.82)

Wrt your edited question, unbiasedness requires that $\Bbb E(\epsilon |X) = 0$. Consistency additionally requires LLN and Central Limit Theorem. So, under some peculiar cases (e.g. error terms follow a Cauchy distribution), it is possible that unbiasedness does not imply consistency.

Comment: So you are saying that the OLS can be unbiased but not consistent?

Comment: @doremi updated the answer.